# Why are (some) dict views hashable?

Tags: python

In python 3, the `keys()`, `values()`, and `items()` methods provide [*dynamic views*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) of their respective elements.  These were backported to python 2.7 and are available there as `viewkeys`, `viewvalues`, and `viewitems`.  I'm referring to them interchangeably here.

Is there any reasonable explanation for this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4
In [1]: hash({}.keys())
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-3727b260127e> in <module>()
----> 1 hash({}.keys())

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict_keys'

In [2]: hash({}.items())
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-decac720f012> in <module>()
----> 1 hash({}.items())

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict_items'

In [3]: hash({}.values())
Out[3]: -9223363248553358775
```

I found this rather surprising.

---

The python docs [glossary on "hashable"](https://docs.python.org/3.4/glossary.html#term-hashable) says:

> An object is hashable if it has a hash value which never changes
>   during its lifetime (it needs a `__hash__()` method), and can be
>   compared to other objects (it needs an `__eq__()` method). Hashable
>   objects which compare equal must have the same hash value.

Okay, the first part actually checks out; it doesn't appear that the hash of a `dict_values` object will change over its lifetime - even though its underlying values certainly can.

```
In [11]: d = {}

In [12]: vals = d.values()

In [13]: vals.__hash__()
Out[13]: -9223363248553358718

In [14]: d['a'] = 'b'

In [15]: vals
Out[15]: dict_values(['b'])

In [16]: vals.__hash__()
Out[16]: -9223363248553358718
```

But the part about `__eq__()`... well, it doesn't have one of those, actually.

```
In [17]: {'a':'a'}.values().__eq__('something else')
Out[17]: NotImplemented
```

So... yeah.  Can someone make any sense of this?  Is there a reason for this asymmetry that of the three `viewfoo` methods, only `dict_values` objects are hashable?

Comment: Related: [Difference between a set and a view](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24830632) and [Inconsistent behaviour between dict.items and dict.values](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24678047)

Comment: Looks like the `dict_values` having a hash value is an oversight here though.

Answer (score 8):

I believe this occurs because `viewitems` and `viewkeys` provide custom rich comparison functions, but `viewvalues` does not. [Here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/acb30ed7eceb/Objects/dictobject.c#l3591) are the definitions of each view type:

```c
PyTypeObject PyDictKeys_Type = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(&PyType_Type, 0)
    "dict_keys",                                /* tp_name */
    sizeof(dictviewobject),                     /* tp_basicsize */
    0,                                          /* tp_itemsize */
    /* methods */
    (destructor)dictview_dealloc,               /* tp_dealloc */
    0,                                          /* tp_print */
    0,                                          /* tp_getattr */
    0,                                          /* tp_setattr */
    0,                                          /* tp_reserved */
    (reprfunc)dictview_repr,                    /* tp_repr */
    &dictviews_as_number,                       /* tp_as_number */
    &dictkeys_as_sequence,                      /* tp_as_sequence */
    0,                                          /* tp_as_mapping */
    0,                                          /* tp_hash */
    0,                                          /* tp_call */
    0,                                          /* tp_str */
    PyObject_GenericGetAttr,                    /* tp_getattro */
    0,                                          /* tp_setattro */
    0,                                          /* tp_as_buffer */
    Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT | Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_GC,/* tp_flags */
    0,                                          /* tp_doc */
    (traverseproc)dictview_traverse,            /* tp_traverse */
    0,                                          /* tp_clear */
    dictview_richcompare,                       /* tp_richcompare */
    0,                                          /* tp_weaklistoffset */
    (getiterfunc)dictkeys_iter,                 /* tp_iter */
    0,                                          /* tp_iternext */
    dictkeys_methods,                           /* tp_methods */
    0,
};

PyTypeObject PyDictItems_Type = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(&PyType_Type, 0)
    "dict_items",                               /* tp_name */
    sizeof(dictviewobject),                     /* tp_basicsize */
    0,                                          /* tp_itemsize */
    /* methods */
    (destructor)dictview_dealloc,               /* tp_dealloc */
    0,                                          /* tp_print */
    0,                                          /* tp_getattr */
    0,                                          /* tp_setattr */
    0,                                          /* tp_reserved */
    (reprfunc)dictview_repr,                    /* tp_repr */
    &dictviews_as_number,                       /* tp_as_number */
    &dictitems_as_sequence,                     /* tp_as_sequence */
    0,                                          /* tp_as_mapping */
    0,                                          /* tp_hash */
    0,                                          /* tp_call */
    0,                                          /* tp_str */
    PyObject_GenericGetAttr,                    /* tp_getattro */
    0,                                          /* tp_setattro */
    0,                                          /* tp_as_buffer */
    Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT | Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_GC,/* tp_flags */
    0,                                          /* tp_doc */
    (traverseproc)dictview_traverse,            /* tp_traverse */
    0,                                          /* tp_clear */
    dictview_richcompare,                       /* tp_richcompare */
    0,                                          /* tp_weaklistoffset */
    (getiterfunc)dictitems_iter,                /* tp_iter */
    0,                                          /* tp_iternext */
    dictitems_methods,                          /* tp_methods */
    0,
};

PyTypeObject PyDictValues_Type = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(&PyType_Type, 0)
    "dict_values",                              /* tp_name */
    sizeof(dictviewobject),                     /* tp_basicsize */
    0,                                          /* tp_itemsize */
    /* methods */
    (destructor)dictview_dealloc,               /* tp_dealloc */
    0,                                          /* tp_print */
    0,                                          /* tp_getattr */
    0,                                          /* tp_setattr */
    0,                                          /* tp_reserved */
    (reprfunc)dictview_repr,                    /* tp_repr */
    0,                                          /* tp_as_number */
    &dictvalues_as_sequence,                    /* tp_as_sequence */
    0,                                          /* tp_as_mapping */
    0,                                          /* tp_hash */
    0,                                          /* tp_call */
    0,                                          /* tp_str */
    PyObject_GenericGetAttr,                    /* tp_getattro */
    0,                                          /* tp_setattro */
    0,                                          /* tp_as_buffer */
    Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT | Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_GC,/* tp_flags */
    0,                                          /* tp_doc */
    (traverseproc)dictview_traverse,            /* tp_traverse */
    0,                                          /* tp_clear */
    0,                                          /* tp_richcompare */
    0,                                          /* tp_weaklistoffset */
    (getiterfunc)dictvalues_iter,               /* tp_iter */
    0,                                          /* tp_iternext */
    dictvalues_methods,                         /* tp_methods */
    0,
};
```

Notice that `tp_richcompare` is defined as `dictview_richcompare` for `items` and `keys`, but not `values`. Now, the [documentation for `__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) says this:

> A class that overrides `__eq__()` and does not define `__hash__()` will have its `__hash__()` implicitly set to None.
>
> ...
>
> If a class that overrides `__eq__()` needs to retain the implementation
>   of `__hash__()` from a parent class, the interpreter must be told this
>   explicitly by setting `__hash__ = <ParentClass>.__hash__`.
>
> If a class that does not override `__eq__()` wishes to suppress hash
>   support, it should include `__hash__ = None` in the class definition.`

So, because `items`/`keys` are overriding `__eq__()` (by providing a `tp_richcompare` function), they would need to explicitly define `__hash__` as being equal to the parent's to retain an implementation for it. Because `values` doesn't override `__eq__()`, it inherits the `__hash__` from `object`, because `tp_hash` and `tp_richcompare` [get inherited from the parent if they're both NULL](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_hash):

> This field is inherited by subtypes together with tp_richcompare: a
>   subtype inherits both of tp_richcompare and tp_hash, when the
>   subtype’s tp_richcompare and tp_hash are both NULL.

The fact that the impelmentation for `dict_values` isn't preventing this automatic inheritence would probably be considered a bug.

Comment: Thanks dano.  Appreciate and agree with your findings.  Seems like `tp_hash` (for all three, really) should be explicitly be set to `PyObject_HashNotImplemented` in order to fix.  I'll open an issue on the bug tracker.

Comment: Looks like @roippi filed [issue22192](http://bugs.python.org/issue22192) for this, for anyone interested.

Comment: This bug still exists (15 Sep 2019) over five years later. I discovered it myself recently and found this question and answer today. I can work around it in my code, but it is unfortunate that it has not been fixed after such a long time.